# Find the approximate number of messages (n) that need to be tried

Tags: probability-theory, computer-networks, hash

Find the approximate number of messages (n) that need to be tried
before finding two that had the same message digest (size k) with probability 0.8.
You need to find n as a function of k . What is n when k= 2^(160) ?

please guide me how to start to solve this question

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your (home-)work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of the [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). The explanation of that should get you started.

Comment: it's about Hash Functions

Comment: @user155971 Yes. So? (Hint: Hash functions are mentioned in the linked article.)